# Upgrading to ubuntu 14.04 from ubuntu 13.10

Tags: upgrade

how to upgrade ubuntu 13.10 to ubuntu 14.04 ?  It gives an error that "third party sources are disabled couldn't get software list"

Answer (score 0):

Go to Software & Updates --> Other Software tab and check the third-party repositories listed there.  See image below

[image]

Comment: It is still not working. What if i upgrade through usb then will all of the installed programs remain or they will be erased ?